# where to declare classes and functions in java

Tags: java, class, declaration

```
 public class demo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
}
```

I just started to learn java, I have c++ experience, and the layout confuses me. for example if I declare a function in the demo class would that make it a function or method. also if I want to declare a class can I declare it outside the demo class or it must be inside the demo class.

thank you.

Comment: Function and methods are same. If you want to declare another class outside demo than it should not be declared public.

Comment: I suggest reading a starter tutorial for Java, they cover such stuff almost always in the first lesson

Comment: The [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You have already declared it. The thing you are missing is your function body.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

should be

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   //DO Some Stuff
}
```

Now here is some additional info:
The main function will be started whenever the application is started and the

> String[] args

are the arguments that you are going to pass while starting the application. 
You can declare as many functions as you want within your class

```
public class demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      //Do Some Stuff
    }
    private void someFunction(){
      //Do Some Stuff
    }
}
```

For more you can start learning some basics from the internet. There are tons of tutorials. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Technically static methods aren't functions. But they are often used as such.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there are no functions. There are only methods.

You can declare methods inside of class definitions. And methods can be static or not static. Just like in C++.

Also there's no need for header files.

Example:

```
public class Demo {

  // This is a constructor
  public Demo() {
  }

  // This is a non-static method
  public void method() {
  }

  // This is a static method. 
  // (It's also a special entry point to start the program)
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }
}
```

I think it's safe to say that Java is much simpler than C++.

Ps. I capitalized **Demo** because according to Java's camel case convention, classes should start with an uppercase letter and methods with lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

you can write code like that

```
public class Emp{
  //Instance variable or class level variable even variable as static 
  String id;
  String name;
  //static variable

  static int count=0;    
  {
    //non static block
  }
  static{ 
      // static block
  }

  public Emp(){
   //default constructor
  }
  //parameterized constructor

  public Emp(String id, String name){
       this.id=id;
       this.name=name;

    }
  // Non-Static Method

  public String getId(){
      return id;
  }
  public String getName(){
     return name;
  }

  //Main method
   public static void main(String[] args){
      //Instance of class
       Emp emp=new Emp("1","Xyz");
       System.out.println(emp.getId());
       System.out.prinln(emp.getName());
   }
}
```